# Grails Form Submission Fails with Dynamic Fields using JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, grails, dynamic

I am using JQuery to show/hide divs that contain form fields. If a certain value from one drop down is selected, the div corresponding to the dependent form field is shown, otherwise it isn't. Grails does not allow the form to be submitted unless the dependent form field is shown. Anyone experience something similar? If so, what work around did you implement? Thanks.

Relevant code is as follows:

```
1. create.gsp
<g:form url="[resource:dvdRequesterInstance, action:'save']" >
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>

2. _form.gsp
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: dvdRequesterInstance, field: 'dvdRequesterPosition', 'error')} required">
    <label for="dvdRequesterPosition" class="extended-label-width">
        <g:message code="dvdRequester.dvdRequesterPosition.label" />
    </label>
    <g:select name="dvdRequesterPosition" required="" id="position" from="${Position.list()}" value="${fieldValue(bean:dvdRequesterInstance, field:'dvdRequesterPosition')}" optionKey="positionName" optionValue="positionName" noSelection="['':'Select Position']" /><span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" id="otherPosition" class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: dvdRequesterInstance, field: 'dvdRequesterOtherPosition', 'error')} required">
    <label for="dvdRequesterOtherPosition" class="extended-label-width">
        <g:message code="dvdRequester.dvdRequesterOtherPosition.label" />   
    </label>
    <g:textField name="dvdRequesterOtherPosition" required="" value="${fieldValue(bean:dvdRequesterInstance, field:'dvdRequesterOtherPosition')}" id="dvdRequesterOtherPosition" size="40" placeholder="Other Position" /><span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</div>

3. JQuery code in layout file
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#position').on('change', function () {
            if (this.value == 'Other') {
                $("#otherPosition").show();
            } 
            else {
                $("#otherPosition").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you post your code maybe someone could help you 
What did you try so far?

Comment: Edit your post and add your code, you can use the text formatting utilities provided. Also, please read [Help Center -How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have provided the relevant code including the form, form fields, and JQuery responsible for showing/hiding the div. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my answer due has no relation with real issue. I'll try to read something about Grails, anyway hope someone helps you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your problem. This is not related to the Grails actually instead of this is a Browser implementation. One may easily get confused in this problem.

Basically, when you are hiding your field using jQuery, you are not actually removing it from the DOM and you have marked that field as `required`. So when you are attempting to submit the form, validation fails on that hidden field which is not getting displayed since you have hidden it and form is not getting submitted.

(Tip: If you use Chrome, you will get this message in Javascript console.)

The fix for this problem is too simple also. You have two options now:

The first option is that you can remove the `required` attribute from the input field when you are hiding using jQuery and then you can add back that attribute when you displaying again.

The second option is that you can permanenlty remove that `required` attribute and add a small custom jQuery validation to validation that field only when the field is visible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution worked. I used the first option.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow. Is there a way to formally accept an answer? Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Sure, we are here to help. There should be hollow green tick below any answer you want to accept. Just click that answer to accept. Take a one minute tour here http://stackoverflow.com/tour